# Regex - allow alpha/num (ąę etc too) and only one space

Tags: regex

I need to modify this pattern. Its working good when string have only one space between words. But I can have sometimes double space (I want only one), so I must add some count to my pattern, but I dont have idea how to do it

```
/^\w+( +\w+)*$/u
```

Comment: The pattern supports 1 or more spaces between words - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VuWJPH/1). If you want to only support 1 space, remove `+` after space in the pattern. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VuWJPH/2).

Comment: Then remove the plus sign after the space.

Comment: Btw what language do you use?

Comment: @mrzasa I'm using php